# Best way to implement a functionality that reads data every second in the background

Tags: android, android-service, android-workmanager, background-service, foreground-service

I am currently rewriting/updating the app that had a background service that was reading CAN data and processing it.

Data is being updated every second and it is either stored or if the value meets specific criteria the app is being launched.

We are now moving to Android 12 and I am wondering how to accomplish that. Based on my short research I can either use the:

- Work manager, but I don't think the tasks can be scheduled every second.
- Foreground service, but this will mean that the user will be informed by an icon in the top ribbon that the task is running (might be acceptable...)
- Job scheduler, I am not sure whether there is any significant advantage over the work manager

Am I missing any other options or misunderstanding any of the three options mentioned above?

I will be thankful for any ideas and comments

Thanks